# Can't get computer to recognize any USB devices except for mouse

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I get the "USB Device not recognized" error with my wireless network adaptor and any USB thumbdrive, same as this person here described: [How do I resolve the error message "USB Device Not Recognized"?](https://superuser.com/questions/385859/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-message-usb-device-not-recognized)

I've already tried the recommended solution, to copy the usb.inf and usb.pnf files. However, that doesn't work.

Also, tried system restore, which doesn't resolve the problem.

My mouse is a USB mouse which works fine. I've tried unplugging the wireless network adaptor and plugging it in again. However, that doesn't help. I thought of using my USB thumbdrive to reinstall the wireless network adaptor driver, but it doesn't even recognize my USB thumbdrive.

What should I do now? I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: I had pretty much the identical symptoms, but can't remember what the fix was.  (Thought I had commented here on it but can't find the comment.)

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling that I found a description on the web of how to use *regedit* to reset the USB config.